# c# - strategy for caching lookups to a hierarchy

Tags: c#, caching, dictionary

I query a hierarchical data source like this:

```
repository.LookupValue(IEnumerable<string> ascendants)
```

where `ascendants` is a list of strings representing the path to the node being looked up.

I would like to cache results from these lookups. I had envisioned using a `Dictionary<IEnumerable<string>, long>`, but it seems when using an `IEnumerable<string>` as a dictionary key, reference equality is used, which is no good to me.

I could of course define my own type wrapping `IEnumerable<string>` and override it's `.Equals` method, but that seems extreme.

Am I missing a simpler solution to the caching problem? Can anyone advise?

Comment: What kinds of values will your keys have?  Using an `IEnumerable` for a key just seems...off.

Comment: I agree. But that's the parameter used for the lookup. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Dictionary` but use the constructor that takes an `IEqualityComparer`. Write a custom implementation of this to compare your collection of ascendants and pass it in.

Here's an example (comparing arrays in this case) that uses built in `StructuralComparisons`.

```
    public class StringArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<string[]>
    {
        public bool Equals(string[] x, string[] y)
        {
            return StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(x, y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(string[] obj)
        {
            return StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(obj);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the right answer to my question. But `StructuralEqualityComparer` seems to be a no-no. It returns the same hash code for any two double-element string arrays whose first elements are the same (i.e. even though the second elements are different). Thank heavens for unit tests.

Comment: @David That's not what I'm seeing - `Array`'s implementation of `IStructuralEquatable.GetHashCode()` seems to consider the last 8 elements. But in any case, you can of course implement your own.

Comment: Sorry, I was using `IEnumerable<string>`, not `string[]` as I stated. But yeah, `StructuralEqualityComparer `seems not to be trusted.

Comment: In the end, I just used a string as the key, creating the string by concatenating all the array's elements together with an arbitrary separator. It's ugly, but less error-prone imho.